# Need help figuring out why my if statement won't pass in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm making a multiplayer game and this is for the ranking list at the end. The weird thing is that the `if statement` doesn't pass, even though when I print `gmD` and `name` they are the same.

Any suggestions?

```
void Awake()
{
    print("scoreBoard");

    foreach (string p in GManageer.deadPlayers)
    {
        scoreString += p + "\n";
    }
    scoreText.text = scoreString;

    string gmD = GManageer.winner;
    string name = controllsManager.username;

    print(gmD + ":gmD");
    print(name + ":name");

    if (gmD == name)
    {
        print("In here too");
        scoreText.text = "Yes, you won!";
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("XP", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("XP") + (int)(70 / PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Lvl")));
    }
}
```

Comment: By "they are the same" you surely mean you watched them in your debugger. I´m pretty sure you have some characters within one of the strings that you can´t see in the debugger, e.g. some whitespace

Comment: You can try to loop over all characters within your 2 strings, and display them. Now see which one is different. You can have a character surrounded by two quotes `'a'` to see it more distinctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes most likely the 2 strings aren't exactly the same. 
When comparing strings you can use the [string.Equal()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.8) function to add comparison settings.

if(gmD.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

*Compare strings using culture-sensitive sort rules, the invariant culture, and ignoring the case of the strings being compared.*

Also a small thing to note is using name for your variable name can lead to some bugs since UnityEngine.Object.name is a property.

Comment: Thank you! I did as you said and it fixed my problem. I will be cautious of it next time.